# Getting original line number for exception in concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-2.7, concurrency, concurrent.futures

Example of using concurrent.futures (backport for 2.7):

```
import concurrent.futures  # line 01
def f(x):  # line 02
    return x * x  # line 03
data = [1, 2, 3, None, 5]  # line 04
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(len(data)) as executor:  # line 05
    futures = [executor.submit(f, n) for n in data]  # line 06
    for future in futures:  # line 07
        print(future.result())  # line 08
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print future.result()  # line 08
  File "C:\dev\Python27\lib\site-packages\futures-2.1.4-py2.7.egg\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 397, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\dev\Python27\lib\site-packages\futures-2.1.4-py2.7.egg\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 356, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

String `"...\_base.py", line 356, in __get_result"` is not endpoint I expected to see. Is it possible to get real line where exception was thrown? Something like:

```
  File "C:\test.py", line 3, in f
    return x * x  # line 03
```

Python3 seems to show correct line number in this case. Why can't python2.7? And is there any workaround?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the original exception traceback gets lost in the ThreadPoolExecutor code. It stores the exception and then re-raises it later. Here is one solution. You can use the **traceback** module to store the original exception message and traceback from your function *f* into a string. Then raise an exception with this error message, which now contains the line number etc of *f*. The code that runs *f* can be wrapped in a *try*...*except* block, which catches the exception raised from ThreadPoolExecutor, and prints the message, which contains the original traceback.

The code below works for me. I think this solution is a little hacky, and would prefer to be able to recover the original traceback, but I'm not sure if that is possible.

```
import concurrent.futures
import sys,traceback


def f(x):
    try:
        return x * x
    except Exception, e:
        tracebackString = traceback.format_exc(e)
        raise StandardError, "\n\nError occurred. Original traceback is\n%s\n" %(tracebackString)



data = [1, 2, 3, None, 5]  # line 10

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(len(data)) as executor:  # line 12
    try:
        futures = [executor.submit(f, n) for n in data]  # line 13
        for future in futures:  # line 14
           print(future.result())  # line 15
    except StandardError, e:
        print "\n"
        print e.message
        print "\n"
```

This gives the following output in python2.7:

```
1
4
9




Error occurred. Original traceback is
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "thread.py", line 8, in f
   return x * x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

The reason your original code gives the right location when run in Python 3 and not 2.7 is that in Python 3 exceptions carry the traceback as an attribute, and when re-raising an exception, the traceback is extended rather than replaced. The example below illustrates this:

```
def A():
    raise BaseException("Fish")

def B():
    try:
        A()
    except BaseException as e:
        raise e

B()
```

I ran this in **python 2.7** and **python 3.1**. In 2.7 the output is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceptions.py", line 11, in <module>
    B()
  File "exceptions.py", line 9, in B
    raise e
BaseException: Fish
```

i.e. the fact that the exception was originally thrown from *A* is not recorded in the eventual output. When I run with **python 3.1** I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceptions.py", line 11, in <module>
    B()
  File "exceptions.py", line 9, in B
    raise e
  File "exceptions.py", line 7, in B
    A()
  File "exceptions.py", line 3, in A
    raise BaseException("Fish")
BaseException: Fish
```

which is better. If I replace `raise e` with just `raise` in the except block in *B*, then **python2.7** gives the complete traceback. My guess is that when back-porting this module for **python2.7** the differences in exception propagating were overlooked.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explaination and sorry for late acceptance.

Answer (score 43):

I was in your same situation and I really needed to have the traceback of the raised exceptions.
I was able to develop this workaround which consists in using the following subclass of the
`ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
import sys
import traceback
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class ThreadPoolExecutorStackTraced(ThreadPoolExecutor):

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        """Submits the wrapped function instead of `fn`"""

        return super(ThreadPoolExecutorStackTraced, self).submit(
            self._function_wrapper, fn, *args, **kwargs)

    def _function_wrapper(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        """Wraps `fn` in order to preserve the traceback of any kind of
        raised exception

        """
        try:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            raise sys.exc_info()[0](traceback.format_exc())  # Creates an
                                                             # exception of the
                                                             # same type with the
                                                             # traceback as
                                                             # message
```

If you use this subclass and run the following snippet:

```
def f(x):
    return x * x

data = [1, 2, 3, None, 5]
with ThreadPoolExecutorStackTraced(max_workers=len(data)) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(f, n) for n in data]
    for future in futures:
        try:
            print future.result()
        except TypeError as e:
            print e
```

the output will be something like:

```
1
4
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "future_traceback.py", line 17, in _function_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "future_traceback.py", line 24, in f
    return x * x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

25
```

The problem is in the usage of `sys.exc_info()` by the `futures` library. From the
documentation:

> This function returns a tuple of three values that give information about the exception that is
>   currently being handled. [...]
>   If no exception is being handled anywhere on the stack, a tuple containing three None values is
>   returned. Otherwise, the values returned are (type, value, traceback). Their meaning is: type gets
>   the exception type of the exception being handled (a class object); value gets the exception
>   parameter (its associated value or the second argument to raise, which is always a class instance
>   if the exception type is a class object); traceback gets a traceback object which encapsulates the
>   call stack at the point where the exception originally occurred.

Now, if you look at the source code of `futures` you can see by yourself why the traceback is
lost: when an exception raises and it is to be set to the `Future` object only
`sys.exc_info()[1]` is passed. See:

https://code.google.com/p/pythonfutures/source/browse/concurrent/futures/thread.py (L:63)
https://code.google.com/p/pythonfutures/source/browse/concurrent/futures/_base.py (L:356)

So, to avoid losing the traceback, you have to save it somewhere. My workaround is to wrap
the function to submit into a wrapper whose only task is to catch every kind of exception and
to raise an exception of the same type whose message is the traceback. By doing this, when an
exception is raised it is captured and reraised by the wrapper, then when `sys.exc_info()[1]`
is assigned to the exception of the `Future` object, the traceback is not lost.

Comment: I looked at lots of answers on SO and this one worked for me - thanks.  I could not get the stack trace with line numbers using other methods, even more recent ones. Strange that this is still an issue with concurrent futures.

Comment: Elegant OOP solution with proper use of overriding. Thanks!

Comment: Anything more baked-in into the library, four years later? I think with a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` more tricks may be necessary, because without changes the `submit` method will fail on "cannot pickle 'weakref' object"

Comment: Nice idea. I think you might want to trap `BaseException`, not just `Exception`.

Comment: As another commenter pointed out, on 3.9 it fails with `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object`

Comment: This is slick but I ran into a problem trying it with certain exceptions - when I went to log the exception. The exception's __str__() (which I called later trying to log the thing) was generating a TypeError within the traceback module - trying to compare an int and KeyError presumably trying to reference the missing trace.

The solution was to create a bog standard Exception instead, re-packaging the trace into the message as before.

Comment: I also used this solution but also ran into problems with certain exceptions (here with boto3 and SSL connections). Probably it's related to what @drizzo4shizzo experienced. Some exceptions even carry payload in binary and it made this threads crash in unexpected ways. We changed our code to asyncio (to avoid "hacks" to the standard library)

Comment: Great! I wasn't getting anything at all from errored handled threads using. `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor `. with your idea + a print() Now I see where it's exploding.

Answer (score 7):

Taking inspiration from the first answer, here it is as a decorator:

```
import functools
import traceback


def reraise_with_stack(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            traceback_str = traceback.format_exc(e)
            raise StandardError("Error occurred. Original traceback "
                                "is\n%s\n" % traceback_str)

    return wrapped
```

Just apply the decorator on the executed function:

```
@reraise_with_stack
def f():
    pass
```

Comment: `StandardError` [has been removed with python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49053930/940592).

Comment: This looks nice, but doesn't work with `ProcessPoolExecutor`