# Python : NameError: name 'StandardError' is not defined

Tags: python, sst

I'm currently developing a website with the SST - Web Test Framework (i'm very beginner) but I have a problem with python

I used this Link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sst/0.2.2

I m using - Python 3.6.4 and SST - Web Test Framework- Latest Version: 0.2.4

My Code is:

```
from sst.actions import *
go_to('http://www.google.com/')
```

Error is:

```
C:\Python\scrapy-master\Projects>python proxyhar.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "proxyhar.py", line 1, in <module>
from sst.actions import *
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sst\actions.py", line 104, in <module>
class EndTest(StandardError):
NameError: name 'StandardError' is not defined
```

Anyone suggest me how to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a bug in SST. Given that it hasn't been updated in five years I'd ditch it.

Comment: if you try doing the test like assert_title_contains('google')
do you still get an error?

Comment: You get the error even without `go_to('http://www.google.com/')`, right?

Comment: @Evusas Yes, I write only from sst.actions import * this line then also its getting same error

Comment: @Fix3r Yes.....

Comment: Do you need to install the module through pip install?

Comment: @Daniel'O'Brien got it right. It's just Python2 has `StandardError` class, but you must be using Python3. You could create virtual environment with Python2 and install this module through `pip` there if you want to keep using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sst only supports Python 2 even though pip will let you install it for Python 3. The error `NameError: name 'StandardError' is not defined` is from sst trying to use the built in exception StandardError which was removed in Python 3. To resolve this, you can either use a different module (which I would recommend) or downgrade to Python 2.7.